# Unmarshalling property fails in Grails and ElasticSearch

Tags: grails, orm, nhibernate-mapping, unmarshalling, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.5.0 and ElasticSearch 0.0.4.6! I have the following domain classes:

```
Class Library {
    --- code omitted ---
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
    static searchable = true
    --- code omitted ---
}

Class Book {
    --- code omitted ---
    static belongsTo = [library:Library]
    static searchable = true
    --- code omitted ---
}
```

I try to search for books like this:

```
--- code omitted ---
def events = elasticSearchService.search(
            {
                query_string(fields: ["Name"],
                        query: query)
                suggest : { suggest_mode: 'popular' }
            })

    render events as JSON
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR unmarshall.DomainClassUnmarshaller  - Error unmarshalling
>   property 'library' of Class Book with id 2 Message: Property
>   Book.library is not mapped as [component], but broken search hit
>   found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the 'library' property of Book domain as component.

In your book domain replace your below code

> static searchable = true

with

> static searchable = {
>           library component: true
>       }

See [elastic plugin document](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/docs/index.html#searchableComponentReference) for more details